# Detect changes in DB Entry

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there any build-in possibility to detect, if an `POCO` entry changed on DB?
For example:

1. User 1 edits Object with ID 1.
2. User 2 also edits Object with ID 1 and saves.
3. User 1 also saves and overwrites changes of User 2.

I tried reloading the object and compare it, but that's a little too complicated.

So what i want to achieve is to check automatically if the object changed in database before i save the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a concurrency token.

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    [ConcurrencyCheck] 
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

With the above, step #3 will never happen. When the second user goes to save their changes, the database will not allow it. EF will throw a concurrency exception when you try to save changes, since the second edit's version does not match. I believe the exact exception type is `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`.

If you are using the fluent API and don't want those attributes on your entity, do this:

```
Property(x => x.Version).IsConcurrencyToken(true).IsRowVersion();
```

**Update**

I take back my comment below, sort of....

Using code first (not EDMX), there is a way to apply these properties globally. I did it once, and am now trying to undo it, slowly. What you can do is implement an abstract entity, then have all of your other entities inherit from it:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [ConcurrencyCheck] 
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }

    // can also do this globally in FluentAPI with custom EntityTypeConfiguration
}

public class SomeEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

However, having done this, I **do not recommend it**. Others may disagree, but I believe you should only enforce concurrency on entities when there is a good reason to.

Comment: Thanks! That's exaclty what i was looking for. Is there maybe also a possibility to set this setting global to whole tables or even a whole .edmx?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not sure. Now that you know how to do it for one entity though, you can search the web and ask another SO question about how to apply concurrency globally to an entire entity model at once.

Answer (score 0):

do not know of any build in ways but I the way that I would choose would be adding audit fields like it is described in the following article

http://www.jigar.net/articles/viewhtmlcontent344.aspx